# Insertar array post php mysql

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Buen día foro.

Dispongo de un formulario donde mando llamar dos input number  donde su propiedad name llamo un array `<input type='number' class='form-control' name='cantidad[]' id='cantidad[]' value='"+cantidad+"'` tomando en cuenta que el array puede traer mas de 2 elementos, como los grego a una base datos(tabla) por medio del método post.

Este es mi formulario.En el id detalles se anexa mis inputs number de cantidad desde js y en la etiqueta  se muestra los datos.

```
        <form method="POST" id="formulario" name="formulario">  
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-ms-2 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Peso:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $inputs->peso; ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-ms-2 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Tarimas:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="tarimas" id="tarimas" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $inputs->tarimas; ?>">
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
                                <button id="btnAgregarArt" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mostrar()"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Agregar Productos</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="resultados"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-ms-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12">
                            <table id="detalles" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                                <thead style="background-color: #A9D0F5" >
                                    <th class="text-center">Opciones</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Modelo</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Piezas</th>

                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Verificado</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Actualizar Conteo</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th><h4 id="total"></h4><input type="hidden" name="total_piezas" id="total_piezas"></th>
                                </tfoot>

                                <tbody>


                                </tbody>

                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-ms-12 col-xs-12" id="guardar">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnGuardar"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="cancelarForm()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"  id="btnCancelar"> </i> Cancelar </button>
                        </div>
                </form>
```

este es mi js donde mando llamar mi cantidad[], mediante una función

```
function agregarDetalle(idProducto,modelo){

var  cantidad = 1;
var teorico = 1;
if(idProducto != ""){


    var fila ="<tr class='filas' id='fila" + cont +"'>" +
                 "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='eliminarDetalle("+cont+")'>x</button></td>" +
                 "<td><input type='text' name='idProducto[]' value='"+idProducto+"'>"+modelo+"</td>" +
                 "<td><input type='number' class='form-control' name='cantidad[]' id='cantidad[]' value='"+cantidad+"'></td>" +
                 "<td><input type='hidden' class='form-control' name='c' id='c' value='"+teorico+"'></td>" +

             "</tr>";
             cont++;
             detalles = detalles + 1;
             $("#detalles").append(fila);
             modificarSubtotales();
             evaluar();


}else{

    alert("Error, al ingresar los datos del productos, favor de revisar producto");
}
```

}

En la imagen es donde agrego mis items de las piezas que voy ir agregando y pueden ser mas de dos modelos y cada modelo sus piezas, el punto es registrar esa cantidad de piezas por el metodo post. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi petición ajax.

```
$("#formulario").submit(function(event){
$("#btnGuardar").attr("disabled",true);

var parametros = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"index.php?action=addIngresos",
    data: parametros,
    beforeSend:function(objeto){
        $("#resultados").html("Mensaje:Cargando...");
    },
    success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados").html(datos).fadeIn();
        $("#resultados").html(datos);
        $("#btnGuardar").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
event.preventDefault();
```

})

Este mi php de ingreso, todos los mando llamar desde mi formulario por el metodo post.

```
<?php 
if(count($_POST) > 0){
    $ing = new CountData();
    $ing->ubicacion = $_POST["ubicacion"];
    $ing->producto_id = $_POST["idProducto"];
    $ing->folio_id = $_POST["idIngreso"];
    $ing->piezas = $_POST["cantidad"];
    $ing->process_id = $_POST["indI"];
    $ing->add();

}
print "<script>alert('Ingreso registrado satisfactoriamente');</script>";
```

?>

Ejecutando, obtengo este error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\solicitud\core\app\model\CountData.php on line 17
```

Donde no me esta tomando bien mi arreglo o lo estoy haciendo mal. Esta es mi función agregar(add) y quien tiene datos del array es piezas que es mi linea 17. Alguien sabe como puedo pasar los datos e insertarlos

```
public function add()
    {
        $sql = " insert into ".self::$tablename. " (ubicacion,producto_id,folio_id,piezas,process_id)";
        $sql .= " value (\"$this->ubicacion\",$this->producto_id,$this->folio_id,$this->piezas,$this->process_id)";
        return Executor::doit($sql);
    }
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿el campo `piezas` de tu base de datos de qué tipo es? ¿qué es lo que pretendes insertar en ese campo, el array entero o la cantidad de piezas? Si es la cantidad de piezas tendrás que hacer un conteo del array y pasar ese dato, no todo el array: `$ing->piezas = count($_POST["cantidad"]);` Por otra parte, ¿eres consciente de que tu código tiene un grave agujero de seguridad, que te pueden inyectar código malicioso por medio de la consulta?

Comment: Gracias por responder @A. Cedano el tipo de datos int y sólo quiero ingresar los datos de piezas(número! Cantidad de piezas

Comment: Ever entonces modifica el código como te dije en el comentario anterior, usando `count`

Comment: Gracias ya lo cambie y probe, y me inserta el numero de elementos qye tengo mas no las el numero de piezas capturados en el input number.

Comment: Ever en el código que has compartido no existe ningún input llamado `cantidad`...

Comment: Acabo de editar mi pregunta y añadi mi funcion js de donde mando llamar cantidad.

Comment: Entonces ¿el error en concreto cuál es ahora? Por cierto, en tu `$sql` tienes un error en la segunda línea, tienes `value` y debería ser `values`.

Comment: este es mi error: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\solicitud\core\app\model\CountData.php on line 17, si utilizo count lo que hace es que agrega el numero de elementos que se encuentran es decir agrego dos item con cantidad o piezas de 10, 15 piezas en el input number, lo que se agrega es el numero 2, cuenta los elementos y los inserta. Al parecer no esta validando el contenido que traigo en cantidad desde el metodo post

Comment: No logro entenderte. El error te dice que eso es un array, y tú no puedes insertar un array en una columna `INT` de la base de datos. Lo demás que dices al final del comentario, no entiendo a qué se refiere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre esta opcion a lo que queria, se los agradesco, saludos.

```
    $num_elementos = 0;
     $num = 0;


     while($num_elementos < count($total_folios) && $num < count($total_cantidad))
     {
        $ing->producto_id = $total_folios[$num_elementos];
        $num_elementos=$num_elementos + 1;
        $ing->piezas = $total_cantidad[$num];
        $num=$num+1;
        $ing->add();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes inputs nombrados para ser arrays, lo que tu obtienes son arrays en tu variable $_POST.

Entonces, el problema es que tú estas intentando guardar arrays en los campos de tu tabla de tipo string o int y por ende, te muestra ese aviso.

Para guardar correctamente cada información en un registro, tendrás que recorrer los arrays con un ciclo y hacer el insert.

O podrías convertir tus arrays en un string. **OJO**: Todo depende de como vayas a guardar tus datos.

```
<?php
 $array = array('apellido', 'email', 'teléfono');
 $separado_por_comas = implode(",", $array);

 echo $separado_por_comas; // apellido,email,teléfono
?>
```

---

### Replicar NOTICE

Abre phptester.net y añade

```
<?php
    $stuff = array(1,2,3);
    print $stuff;  //PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in yourfile on line 3
?>
```

Verás el error que te aparece y de lo que te hablo.

Comment: Gracias por responder Hoose, como seria para recorrelo y solo agregar datos de tipo int en  mi base de datos, estoy intentando con foreach pero solo me ingresa el último registro  ` $total_cantidad = $_POST["cantidad"]; foreach ($total_cantidad as  $total) { echo "<br>".$total; $ing->piezas = $total;}` al imprimirlo si me muestra los datos pero al insertalo solo ingresa el último agregado.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el $_POST['cantidad'] contiene un arreglo, estas intentando insertar todo el arreglo dentro de un solo campo lo cual no se  puede, tal cual lo estas haciendo, lo que tendrías que hacer en tu php es convertir el arreglo $_POST['cantidad'] en un solo string para que lo puedas insertar en el campo de tu tabla. De esta manera conviertes el arreglo en un string:

```
<?php
$cantidad = implode('/', $POST['cantidad']);
?>
```

Si tu imprimes esto te da un solo string que contiene todos los valores separados por un "/", algo como "valor1/valor2/valor3", y este string lo podrías insertar en un campo de tabla que tendría que ser "Varchar" o "Text". Si tu después quieres acceder a esos valores trayendo el string de tu base de datos podrías hacerlo, supongamos que el string de que trajiste de tu base de datos lo almacenaste en la variable $cantidadStr, entonces:

```
<?php
  $cantidadArray = explode('/', $cantidadStr);
?>
```

Esto te devolvería un arreglo como $CantidadArray = ["valor1", "valor2", "valor3"];